# Django serve various file types using IIS / Virtual Directory

Tags: python, django, windows, iis

I am trying to serve various file types using Django on a IIS windows server. And for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out.

I am working with a legacy DB that stores file paths in a column. The files are held on a network share so have created a Virtual Folder (tired pass-though and connect as)

I get the URLS created in HTML using the file path from the DB / model

```
<td><a href ="/{{doc.location}}" download>{{doc.location}}</a></td>
```

which results in `http://panel/docs/07/xxxxxx.doc`

File downloads but get a Fail - No file in Chrome.

The files are mix of doc / pdf/ txt and a few other file types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, racking my brain with this.

Comment: I tested it on my windows server by using simple html page, it can work and file downloaded in my browser. If you directly enter url of doc.location, can you access it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried {{doc.location}} and it does not work since it adds it to the end of the current page. http://panel/allFileSearch/docs/07/05738829PMXC.doc the / is needed to get to the root. Did you try this With Django or just a regular html page?

Comment: I'm not an expert in django, so I just use regular html page. If you can access doc through url but cannot download in django, maybe something wrong with django. But if you cannot access the doc, it must be caused by network share path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `FileField` or `ImageField` as it uses the Django Media Files system to correctly direct to the file's path on your server.

You will need to configure the `MEDIA_URL` the same name as your IIS Virtual Folder.
You can also create a dedicated `FileSystemStorage` to direct to that virtual folder explicitly.

Checkout more information in the Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/.

About the IIS Virtual Directory, check out the `django-windowsauth` package, using the `createwebconfig` management command you can configure your IIS Website automatically and makes sure you configure correctly the Virtual Directory.
https://github.com/danyi1212/django-windowsauth